# how can I spread surefire junit tests across different compute resources

Tags: maven, junit, kubernetes, maven-surefire-plugin

I'd like to spread the execution of junit tests across different systems, when maven surefire is running the tests. Is this possible?

There are ~ 20,000 junit tests, and when running 5 in parallel (forks), it takes approximately 40 minutes. Running more in parallel starts to hit resource problems. If I could run half of the tests classes on a different VM (or something like kubernetes, etc), then that could cut the execution time in half.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unit tests are by definition local and spreading them over to other systems does not make sense...Furthermore the questions is how long all tests need if they run with single thread ? Cause to me it sounds the tests are very slow for unit tests? I suppose those are likely integration tests (or at least some of them)..?

Comment: none run against a deployed system, all are unit tests running on mocked interfaces, though there are some inefficient code blocks/delays. re: 'local by definition', I disagree. I think it needs to run with the compiled objects, but builds are distributed today in ways they weren't previously, seems plausible that unit tests could too.